# Google Sheets xpath query not working

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-docs

Hoping someone smarter than me can help me sort this out! I've been stumped for a few days now trying to pull some data from website into Google Sheet using ImportXML with no luck.

I'm looking to import the average odds for various sporting events from the website Oddsportal.com which update and change throughout the day. I'd like my sheet to also update these odds, similar to stock prices.

For example:

http://www.oddsportal.com/search/San+Jose+Sharks/

I would like to pull the Average Odds for Team "1" (+136) into a cell, the odds for Tie "X"(+277) into a cell and Team "2"(+161) into individual cells. Just the odds portion. If it's unable to be pulled from that page it is also listed on http://www.oddsportal.com/hockey/usa/nhl/san-jose-sharks-nashville-predators-6cPaAHOM/ down at the bottom in the Average Odds Row.

This seems simple enough but I just can't seem to get the ImportXML query correct without an error.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the page's source code (Ctrl-U). The **original html does not contain needed values**, they most likely loaded later thru xhr (ajax) call:

[image]

So most likely you'll not succeed with mere a request html. 
You need to explore Network in the browser DevTools to find out what request is initiated (by JS files) to get needed data. This might be even unique one containing hash signiture, so you'll not reproduce it for future use.

I recommend you to turn to scriping tools for retrieving that info.